# superposing two or more series into one chart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, highcharts

I am trying to fetch data from an oracle database and then plot the data accordingly to a chart. It should be relatively easy but the problem is I have to plot more than one field and superimpose them into the same chart. For example there would be four lines in single chart to specify four different fields.  So far I can put two/multiple series into one chart with the following code   [image]

and the chart looks like this   [image]

But I want them to be superimposed on top of each other. I am not really familiar with asp charts so it would be great to have some valuable input on this.
Thanks. The end result should be something like this -
 [image]

EDIT::: I see what went wrong with the output! So, what I really wanted to know is that those two value in two series will have the same axis or not! I wanted to plot two values with such difference that they couldnt overlap and thought they were using separate axis. So what I am looking for is already here , it was just wrong data values that gave me hard time. The actual figure now looks like - 
[image]

Comment: The position of the chart is determined by it's Y values. If the values are not in the same range then the lines will not overlap. The only thing that you could do is use the second axis, but you could only get to overlap 2 distinct ranges like that I guess. Why would you want to overlap the values that are not in the same ranges?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out! the graph is actually plotting it on the same chartarea, only thing is that the data range is so different that they were far apart and i thought they were being charted as separate plots.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out.